# FBSDK: Cannot read property loginwithreadpermissions of undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, fbsdk

I'm setting up a React Native project using the FBSDK for login purpose.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I ran `npm install react-native-fbsdk --save`
2. I ran `react-native link`
3. I followed each step mentioned there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/
4. I double checked using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAXVKapP5cM

However, I still get this red screen error:

`Cannot read property logInWithReadPermissions of undefined` at FBLoginManager.js, line 77 (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBLoginManager.js)

Here's my AppDelegate.m content:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"PegaseBuzzApp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];


  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
}
@end
```

Here's my linked frameworks and binaries:

[image]

EDIT: on my project:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginManager,
} = FBSDK;
```

Plus:

```
_onFBButtonPress () {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Login cancelled');
        } else {
          alert('Login success with permissions: '
            +result.grantedPermissions.toString());
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```

And:

```
<Button onPress={() => this._onFBButtonPress()} buttonStyle={'buttonFb'} labelStyle={'buttonFbText'} label={I18n.t('Login.btnConnectFB')}></Button>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Can you add code from `FBLoginManager.js` please?

Comment: Hi, I just added it in the question : https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBLoginManager.js

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry I thought you have a file called ``FBLoginManager.js` too. Are you using fbsdk anywhere in your project or just added the library?

Comment: I added it to the question. I basically copied/pasted the example given here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#requesting-additional-permissions-with-login-manager

Comment: Add the full file code

Comment: @ParasWatts Done

Comment: If you really installed the library correctly and the code parts you added are in the same file I don't see any reason for this to not work. Is there any other variable called `LoginManager` in your file?

Comment: @bennygenel No, only one `LoginManager` defined here. I'm gonna remove `node_modules`folder and clear npm / watchman cache, because... well... I don't know what's going on...

Comment: import FBSDK, { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'; import like this

Comment: I imported like you imported and login was not successful, I didn't see any error, since I am using release version

Comment: @ParasWatts I did that too, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you correctly linked the project and check if in ios all the files are added after linking. I am using android, do not have much knowledge about ios. I am using fbsdk successfully

Comment: This is in the screenshot I posted "Link binary with libraries"

Comment: You can try downgrading the fbsdk and try.

Comment: npm install react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0 --save 
 react-native link react-native-fbsdk

Comment: @ParasWatts Actually, I already use react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0, since I wasn't able to link react-native-fbsdk@0.6.1. Sorry I didn't say that earlier.

Comment: can you try same code with android ?maybe ios has some issue. I am using in android and not facing any problem.

Comment: I'll try using RN 0.48 (currently using RN 0.44)

Comment: Okay. I am using 0.46.4

Comment: So, RN 0.48.3 + React 16.0.0-alpha.12, still the exact same error. This should comes from the xCode project (linked frameworks) but I'm pretty sure I did this right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just resolved the same error.
For some reason 
   "react-native link react-native-fbsdk"
had finished for Android but not ios.

rnpm-install info Android module react-native-fbsdk is already linked 
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-fbsdk ios dependency 
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-fbsdk has been successfully linked

Try rerunning and make sure you are linking with
   libRCTFBSDK.a

Answer (score 4):

Following @Greg Cockroft's answer, I've noticed that I was not being able to include "libRCTFBSDK.a" on my project's "Link Binary With Libraries" because I was not including the "RCTFBSDK" library project.

So if you are on same situation do the following missing steps:

1. Add (or drag using Finder) "/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj" under your Xcode project "Libraries" group.
2. Build "RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj" or your entire project.
3. Add "libRCTFBSDK.a" on your project settings, under "Link Binary With Libraries".
4. Compile/run your app. Now if you have the right JS login code, you should be able to login via Facebook's screen.

Comment: I'm new to Xcode. I don't understand point 3. Can you explain how I do this?

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen on Xcode you select your project's name on Project Navigator (click ⌘1 if you can't see it).

Then a bit to the right, on "TARGETS" select your app target name and on top select "Build Phases".

Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" and on bottom tap on "+" for adding an item.

Start typing / select "libRCTFBSDK.a", click "Add" and it's done.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function LoginManager.**logInWithPermissions**(['public_profile', 'email']);

Answer (score 0):

Once you did this:

```
npm install react-native-fbsdk --save
react-native link
```

Download latest FacebookSDK to your ~/Documents folder.

Unzip it to ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/

Then rebuild in XCode.

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding to metro.config.js. And make sure you have installed metro-config

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        blacklistRE: blacklist([
            /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
        ])
    },
};
```