# iOs React Native app crashes with libRCTFBSDK.a

Tags: ios, react-native

My issue is related to this one: [FBSDK: Cannot read property loginwithreadpermissions of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274778/fbsdk-cannot-read-property-loginwithreadpermissions-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment79518891_46274778)

Cleaning my app warnings and unused librairies, I noticed I have a warning that says `Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist`.

So, hcecking the docs: `If you get a build error like "Warning: Native component for 'RCTFBLikeView' does not exist," verify that libRCTFBSDK.a shows up in the Link Binary with Libraries section of your build target's Build Phases.`

Actually, I didn't have this file in my Link Binary with Libraries section. So I add it, and then, the app crashes on start (RN splashscreen, then black screen, then iOs home).

Any ideas?

Comment: Any error message on console about the crash?

Comment: Have you linked the FBSDK correctly ?

Comment: @bennygenel No, the debugger isn't ready when the app crashes.

Comment: @ParasWatts My ios setup / libraries link is given there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274778/fbsdk-cannot-read-property-loginwithreadpermissions-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment79518891_46274778

Comment: You can start logs in new console, Sometimes when app crashed there are some logs in logcat. Try to check if crash reason is getting printed in logs or not

Comment: @ParasWatts What do you mean by "new console"?

Comment: I mean in a new screen in your project folder run command react-native log-ios

Comment: and then run the project , sometimes crash logs are printed on console or the terminal whatever you are using.

Comment: @ParasWatts Dear Sir, you made my day. I didn't know about `react-native log-ios`. And this just gave me all informations I needed. I had to add to Info.plist fbauth2, fb-messenger-api, and some more values to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Thanks. I still have issues with this module, but it will be easier now.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: And well, 3 minutes later, I'm able to login via Facebook. Thanks. FTR I actually missed 2 things: adding libRCTFBSDK.a (this isn't said in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#settings). Then, I completely missed step 4 of this doc. I just don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Great. Sometimes we miss little things :)

Comment: Last issue with this: login via Facebook (on iOs simulator, it opens Safari to performs the auth) doesn't close safari window. Console says: Can't close the window since it was not opened by JavaScript

Comment: Well, in all this xCode linking hell, I think react-native link or something else remove my adds to AppDelegate.m...

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with libRCTFBSDK.a but in my case, it was with login functionality.

In my case adding `<string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>` to `<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>` in `Info.plist` solved crashing the app problem.